# Using the Aurelia router, how do I define two routes to the same view?

Tags: aurelia

I have a sub-router. Let's say it's for fancy fruits. In that sub-router, I want to define routes to specific fruits that will show up in the navigation using RouteConfig nav: true as such:

```
config.map([
    { route: [":fruit"], name: "AppleFruit", moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("./fruity-fruit-fruit"), nav: true, title: "Apples are yum!", layoutModel: { fruit: "Apple" } },
    { route: [":fruit"], name: "LemonFruit", moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("./fruity-fruit-fruit"), nav: true, title: "Lemons are for booze!!", layoutModel: { fruit: "Lemon" } }
]);
```

Specifically, I'm wanting to do it this way because there are navigation elements on the page that rely on other routes in this sub-router, and I would like these to appear in the navigation with the others. My thought was that the layoutModel would get passed into the activate params in fruity-fruit-fruit, but it just blows up before making it to that point.

Is this possible, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As often happens, I have found the answer. My problem was that I was using layoutModel instead of just specifying the href. It should have been:

```
config.map([
  { route: [":fruit"], name: "AppleFruit", moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("./fruity-fruit-fruit"), nav: true, title: "Apples are yum!", href: "/fruits/Apple" },
  { route: [":fruit"], name: "LemonFruit", moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("./fruity-fruit-fruit"), nav: true, title: "Lemons are for booze!!", href: "/fruits/Lemon" }
]);
```